# Marking a command as a variable in order to be reused within piped or separate commands

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, io-redirection, variable

In Linux, would it be possible to create a multi-pipe command, serving the same type of command ie: grep however different output alteration done to it?

Strict example:

```
grep 10-Feb file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1,2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20 ; 
grep 10-Feb file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head ; 
grep 10-Feb file-txt [..]
```

Would it be possible to make the first grep and path an argument, and make it automatically apply to the following commands?

```
$=[grep 10-Feb file.txt] | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1,2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20 ; 
$ | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head ; 
$ [..]
```

As an edit:

I cannot set-up the above command in a bash script since I have limited access to root from which I can call the scripts from.

I am interested in assigning a command as a variable from the command line solely.

Comment: You can save the _result_ of the first command, and then reuse it several times.

Answer (score 0):

By "in Linux" you probably mean "in Bash".

And the answer is yes, they are called functions:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html

In ruby (which runs in linux) you can load your code blocks in lambdas (which are unnamed functions)

Comment: Hey Bruno!
I am actually interested in doing in non-bash situations. Essentially interested in running a single command using variables.

In the current case, due to limitations, I cannot use a bash script, solely the commands.

Comment: You know, this answer be a lot more useful [if it didn't rely on only the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) but e.g. gave an example relevant to this situation. Answers with only links also have the risk that the link will rot, making the answer pretty much useless.

Comment: @ilkkachu You are generally right, but I suspect that tldp.org will outlive the SO stack (it is official documentation, not some blog). I also think that OP need to be pointed to some quality bash documentation.

Comment: @Bruno9779, I was under the impression that as a GNU program, Bash's [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) would be maintained by the GNU project. In any case, a document from 2000 might not be the best reference, and this answer does not contain the actual answer, just a pointer.